# I don't want to use Thread.Sleep with SHDocVw.ShellWindows

Tags: c#, winapi, internet-explorer

I have a program where I have to get a SHDocVw.InternetExplorer instance from a running IE8 process. To get the instance the example code below runs. For some reason it won't work without the Thread.Sleep.

The Browser.HWND throws InvalidCastException for all instances in the m_IEFoundBrowsers if the Thread.Sleep is removed. When using the Thread.Sleep it works for the IE8 windows.

Does anyone know how to do this in a way not using Thread.Sleep? (I don't like to use the sleep function, usually it just pushes the problems into the future...)

Example code:

```
InternetExplorer m_IEBrowser = null;  
ShellWindows m_IEFoundBrowsers = new ShellWindowsClass();  
Thread.Sleep(10);                           
foreach (InternetExplorer Browser in m_IEFoundBrowsers)  
{  
    try  
     {  
         if (Browser.HWND == (int)m_Proc.MainWindowHandle)  
         {  
              m_IEBrowser = Browser;  
              break;  
         }  
      }  
      catch(InvalidCastException ice)  
      {  
            //Do nothing. Browser.HWND could not execute for this item.  
      }  
}
```

Comment: What happens before this?  Are you starting IE yourself?  It needs time to start up.

Comment: You'd think `new ShellWindowsClass()` would block until it was ready to be used.

Comment: I'm strting IE myself and it got plenty of time to start. I'll try some more tomorrow but it seems like the sleep has to come after the "new ShellWindowsClass()". I'm not so good on the effects of the VS debugger, but when running the code there and waiting at a breakpoint I get the same problem if I don't have the Thread.Sleep. Maybe the debugger is introducing something else but right now it seems to me that sleeping the thread for some reason is the only thing that lets new ShellWindowsClass() finish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came across the following link which seems to back up Hans's comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/joberg/archive/2005/05/03/405283.aspx

The article states:

> The Internet Controls Library contains
>   the “ShellWindowsClass” which is
>   basically a collection of all the
>   shell windows (e.g.: IE) spawned
>   across the desktop. That component
>   provides an event handler called
>   “Windows Registered” that we are going
>   to hook up to. Once the process has
>   been launched, we will wait until the
>   corresponding window is registered
>   then we are going to connect our
>   Internet Explorer control to the shell
>   window found. To determine if the
>   window is found, we iterate through
>   the registered windows and we try to
>   find a handle that matches the handle
>   of the process we previously launched.
>   We will use the “ManualResetEvent”
>   synchronization primitive to wait a
>   certain amount of time for the window
>   to be registered.

I expect you'd be able to map these ideas across to your problem relatively easily.

Comment: David - I'll try to do something with the article you found tomorrow. It looks promising. I'll post the results.

Comment: This article did the trick. Thanks! I'll show a modification not in the article that I needed in an answer post.

Comment: @Håkan great! glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

The article posted by David solved the problem. The first time the code runs in my program it works as described in the article. But if I exit the program, leave the opened IE8 open, open my program again then the the windows_WindowRegistered method got problems with InvalidCastExceptions. Handling these exceptions as shown below made it work as needed.

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
private void windows_WindowRegistered(int lCookie)
{
    if (process == null)
        return;  // This wasn't our window for sure

    for (int i = 0; i < windows.Count; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            InternetExplorerLibrary.InternetExplorer ShellWindow = windows.Item(i) as InternetExplorerLibrary.InternetExplorer;
            if (ShellWindow != null)
            {
                IntPtr tmpHWND = (IntPtr)ShellWindow.HWND;
                if (tmpHWND == process.MainWindowHandle)
                {
                    IE = ShellWindow;
                    waitForRegister.Set(); // Signal the constructor that it is safe to go on now.

                    return;

                }
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException ice)
        {
            //Do nothing. Browser.HWND could not execute for this item.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for following up for the benefit of other readers. And you now have enough reputation to upvote!